# validation not working after styling dropdownlist asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am working on an asp.net mvc 5 application. The validation fails when I style the div containing "@html.dropdownlistfor" helper and works otherwise.

```
<div class="styled-select slate">
    @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.BreedId, Model.BreedList, Model.BreedId) : 
        Enumerable.Empty<SelectListItem>(), "Please Select a Breed")
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.BreedId)
</div>
```

If i remove the class attribute the validation works. Can someone help with figuring out what the problem is

Comment: What is the purpose of creating a label (null value) option using the 3rd parameter of `DropDownListFor()` (i.e. `Model.BreedId`)? What is `: Enumerable.Empty<SelectListItem>(), "Please Select a Breed")`? You don't appear to be using `DropDownListFor()` correctly and you code does not make sense. Is `Model.BreedList` `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is most probably caused from a conflict between css classes. What you could do is that:

1) Check is there is a class named "valid", "validation", "validate" or something like that in "styled-select slate" class and then update the style for validation.

2) Or you can directly update your validation styles that your project uses currently by using **!important** property after each conflicted set of the style as below:

```
.field-validation-error {
    color: #e80c4d !important;
    font-weight: bold !important;
    padding-left:10px !important;
}
```

Hope this helps...

Comment: Thank you for your reply. As guided by you I went by your option 2 and it worked. But instead of directly updating the css class I wrote the class again at page level and made the changes their, so that it did not affect the validation else where in the project.